# Another app has the same name as mine on the appstore!

Tags: google-play, appstore, trademark

I am about to publish a game on the android playstore and the ios appstore. It is called "PairIt". I checked a while back to see if there were any other apps named PairIt on the playstore, and there were none. But I did not check on the appstore. Yesterday, when I tried publishing my app onto the appstore, it said the name was taken. After looking around on the appstore I saw someone else had an app named PairIt. So what I did was changed my app name to "PairIt!". Will this work? Could I get into any legal troubles for this?

Answer (score 1):

Names can be [trademarked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark). If "PairIt" is already used or registered as a trademark by somebody else, then yes, it is possible you can get into legal trouble if they decide to defend that trademark.

Comment: I read somewhere, they "have to" defend their trademark. Otherwise they may just loose it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark).

Comment: @Kromster They do. But they also have to know about your infringement before they can actively defend against it, and lots of small-scale cases can easily go unnoticed.